# Why does CacheManager cache LogicalPlan instead of PhysicalPlan?

Tags: apache-spark

According to the source of [CacheManager](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/445c5417ea1d7b7f4fb055153eab8fb0f711a183/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/CacheManager.scala#L52), it stores cached elements as a [list](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/445c5417ea1d7b7f4fb055153eab8fb0f711a183/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/CacheManager.scala#L60) of [`CachedData`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/445c5417ea1d7b7f4fb055153eab8fb0f711a183/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/CacheManager.scala#L42), which contains the `plan` parameter of the `LogicalPlan` type.

The logical plan of a query can be transformed later, but the cache doesn't get applied because the logical plan doesn't match the cached plan.

Consider the following two queries:

```py
cached_df = (df
    .select(col("id"))
    .where(col("age") > 18))
).cache()

non_cached_df = (df
    .where(col("age") > 18)
    .select(col("id"))
)
```

The physical plans of the queries will be the same, since they differ only in the sequence of the applied operators. But the `non_cached_df` won't benefit from the cached data that is available after `cached_df`, because their logical plans are different.

What is the reasoning behind the idea of caching only logical plans?